# Google Place API and displaying results on Map - Lagging

Tags: android, google-places-api, retrofit2

We are working on one requirement where we need to display some favorite types of places to the user based on their current location and 5 miles radius. User can search from the Text Field and with each character user will type we are hitting the place API to get the best result.

We are not showing any loading spinner so user have no idea that app is fetching the results in background.There is lot of delay in this process as with each character we are making call and updating the map. Is there any possible way in retrofit we can cancel the previous request for each new character entered and initiate a new call.

Any other workaround to get rid of this delay and make the execution faster for fetching and displaying the results back to user.

Answer (score 0):

You show get the latitud and longitud by google maps api, the you can use this Location.distanceBetween() then you just put google markers and that will be more helpful.